# ADS retrieve whenchanged with AM or PM

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have a vbs file that queries the domain as below

```
queryTxt = "<"& domainname &">;" & _
  "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person));" 


queryTxt = queryTxt & "SAMAccountName,whenchanged"
```

But in some servers "whenchanged" is returning values as "**8/18/2014 1:20:30 AM**" and in some as "12-08-2014 04:54:58". I want to have the returning value as the **first** date format.

How to update the query so that I get a unique date format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date issue in vb script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895015/date-issue-in-vb-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries to the `whenChanged` attribute return a `Date` value, so the display format is governed by the regional settings of the computer displaying the query results. Either change the date format in the computer's regional settings, or [use a `StringBuilder` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24906047/1630171) for building a custom date format.