# How to create text files with dynamic file name

Tags: vbscript

So far the code below is what I am using. It is running on a Siemens HMI (IPC477d) but when I test the script out, the error I get is

> An Unhandled exception ('Bad File name or number') occurred in HmiRTm.exe[5984].

I want to know where is the mistake in my code.

The line of Code `SmartTags(...)` is part of the Software within HMI for handling PLC tags coming through. So it's just a variable in the PLC Code. The variable itself will always be a string value. I dont know if this was important but I thought I would throw that out there for anyone wondering what is happening with that line of code.

```
Sub CreateTXTReport()
'Tip:
' 1. Use the <CTRL+SPACE> or <CTRL+I> shortcut to open a list of all objects and functions
' 2. Write the code using the HMI Runtime object.
'  Example: HmiRuntime.Screens("Screen_1").
' 3. Use the <CTRL+J> shortcut to create an object reference.
'Write the code as of this position:

    Dim TT,DT
    'If(SmartTags("
    TT = FormatDateTime(Time,3)
    DT = FormatDateTime(Date,0)
    Dim fso, MYfile, strFileName, strFullName, strPath
    strPath = "D:\txtFiles"
    strFileName = "BatchFile_" & DT & "_" & TT & ".txt" 
    SmartTags("BatchFileName") = strFileName
    Const forWriting=1,forReading=2, forAppending=8
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFullName = fso.BuildPath(strPath,strFileName)
    'If (fso.FileExists("D:\txtFiles\" & strFileName)) = True Then
        'Set MYfile = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\txtFiles\" & strFileName, forAppending, True)
    'Else
        'Set MYfile = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\txtFiles\" & strFileName, forWriting, True)
        'MYfile.WriteLine DT & "," & TT & "," & "BatchFile"
    'End If
    If (fso.FileExists(strFullName)) = True Then
        Set MYfile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFullName, forAppending, True)
    Else
        Set MYfile = fso.CreateTextFile(strFullName, forWriting, True)
        MYfile.WriteLine DT & "," & TT & "," & "BatchFile"
    End If
    MYfile.WriteLine(SmartTags("ReportVariable"))

    MYfile.Close
    PrintReport("BatchFile_" & DT & "_" & TT & ".txt" )
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse me, doesn't your **strFileName** have to begin with the slash **'\'**? Or your **strPath** end with it? In order to make a consistent **strFullName**?

Comment: Well the Commented out code included the slashes but it still threw out the same error.

Comment: Nice. Are you sure **DT** and **TT** have valid values (not **':'** or some other special char)?

Comment: @statosdotcom The `BuildPath` method handles path separators when constructing a path, so you don't have to keep track of which part does or doesn't start or end with a backslash. It's pretty likely that a slash or colon in `DT` or `TT` causes the issue, though.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers thank you!

Comment: `strFileName = Replace(Replace("BatchFile_" & DT & "_" & TT & ".txt", "/", ""), ":", "")`

Comment: @JimHewitt That might help, but generally you have better control if you [construct the timestamps yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24906047/1630171). That way you know what the format looks like without having to rely on the system's locale.